# calculate a 90% confidence interval

Tags: statistics

There's a report saying that $67\%$ of teachers surveyed think that computers are now essential tools in the classroom. Suppose that this information was based on a random sample of $n=200$ teachers.

Calculate a $90\%$ confidence interval for $\pi$, the true proportion of teachers who think the computer is essential in the classroom.

I know how to find the confidence interval for mean, variance and s.d., but I'm not sure of how to calculate the confidence interval for $\pi$, can anyone give me a hand and show me how it works please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let p' = sample proportion, and q' = 1 - p', and n = sample size. Also critical value z = 1.65 for the 90% C.I. First compute the error E = z*(p'*q'/n)^(1/2) = 1.65*(.67*.33/200)^(1/2) = 0.054. Thus the C.I = (p' - E , p' + E) = (.67 - .054, .67 + .054) = (.616, .724).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i = 1$ if teacher $i$  think that computers are now essential tools, 
$X_i = 0 \text{ otherwise}$.

You have:
$X_i$ are independant with the same distribution $EX_i=\pi$ and $\rm{Var}X_I = \pi(1- \pi)$.

Then use both mean and sd estimates, and the Central Limit Theorem to compute the confidence interval.